# PHP create directory on http request

Tags: php

I am creating a site with multiple users.  Each user gets a directory like http://example.com/username/  I have created hundreds of directories with this code inside.

```
define("_USER_", basename(__DIR__));
require(__DIR__.'/../index.php');
```

So it gets the main index.php and displays the site to the user and the constant *USER* is used to get the user's data from mySQL.

Is it possible to create a "username" directory when the user requests http://example.com/username/ or is there a means to make it appear to the browser that it is in the requested directory.  Thanks.

Comment: *"I have created hundreds of directories..."* - This seems *really* inefficient.  I imagine it would be a lot easier to maintain to just have URL-rewriting and/or some friendly URL system which passes the values as input to a single script which then displays the relevant information.  For example, a URL like `/home/someusername` could be used to pass the value `"someusername"` to a given script.  Different frameworks do this differently, but overall the principal is the same.  There's really no reason to map all possible URLs to actual files/folders and repeat all that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing is very inefficient. You could redirect all requests of files that doesn't exists to a single index.php. The .htaccess would have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

If `/username/` doesn't exists, `/index.php` will be executed.

Comment: Can I use this to also rewrite the path to http://example.com/username/about.php?  This currently sends all the pages to http://example.com/username/index.php.  Thanks

Comment: You can change `index.php` to `about.php` in the rule.

Comment: But that would send all the pages to about.php.  It needs something to send it to whatever the page is requested.  So any page can be used and it adds the different correct phantom directory.

Comment: The idea of redirecting everything to one file is to be able to route the requests inside the php script. Your code could check the requested URI, find the username and use `include()` to include any file you want.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!